# Executing shell commands in VxWorks 6.9 RTP application

Tags: rtp, vxworks

How can I execute the shell  commands like `dump memory (d())`,  `xbdCreatePartition`, `dosFsVolFormat`, `dosFsShow` from an RTP application program?
Linux provides system commands to do this job, how is this achieved in VxWorks6.9?

Comment: So, what does the VxWorks manual tell you?  What have you tried?  It feels like you might be asking in the wrong place, as you have not asked a specific C++ question.  Perhaps you should look for a VxWorks SO site?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an equivalent of `system()`, to allow you to execute an arbitrary command, you are out of luck.

However, the "Shell" that you are used to interacting with is actually a C interpreter, and any command you are running is available to be called from code. So you could call `dosFsVolFormat` for example from your own code.

There is a caveat here, which is that most functionality is implemented in the kernel, and so these functions may not be available in your RTP. The functions available vary from release to release, and may also be dependant on your kernel configuration. You can compare the user versions of headers to the kernel version to see what might be available.

You can always write your own system calls, however, to expose kernel functionality to a RTP application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call kernel functions directly from RTP. You can create a kernel module project that can take commands from TCP and execute kernel functions for you. And from your RTP project you'd be sending these commands from TCP.  You can use serial channel protocols or message channel, etc instead of TCP.
The main reason for this is to seperate kernel space from application space so that your application won't cause a crash on kernel.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you have a host pc and a target running on vxworks. That means you are using a Cross-compiler IDE such as Windriver Workbench or Tornado.

At this moment, you have 2 possibilities.

1) Your target has an VGA or HDMI port on it so you can easyly plug in a monitor and you can see the vxworks shell operating on a blue screen.

There you can run your shell commands.

https://userweb.jlab.org/~brads/Manuals/VxWorks/vxWorks_commands.html

2) You can use the windriver debugging tool. But you need to add components to your vxworks kernel image such as INCLUDE_DEBUG_AGENT. You can configure it yourself. When you connect your remote device, you can open a shell window and start typing system calls.

https://borkhuis.home.xs4all.nl/vxworks/vxw_pt2.html

Good luck...